# Как массив объектов конвертировать в json формат? flask + sqlalchemy + mysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Всем привет! Работаю с Python + flask + sqlalchemy + MySQL. Хочу получить данные с базы данных и вывести их в JSON формате. Ниже представлен код, который выводит: TypeError: Object of type Tarif is not JSON serializable.

Модель

```
class Tarif(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=False)

def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

def to_dict(self):
    data = [{
        'id': self.id,
        'name': self.name
    }]
    return data
```

получаю данные с базы

```
@tarif.route('/api_/tarifs', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_tarifs():
    tarifs = Tarif.query.all()
    if tarifs is not None:
        return tarifs
```

Была еще одна идея, но тогда вывод слишком нагружает лишними данными. Есть ли более простой и красивый способ?

```
data = {
    'items': [item.to_dict() for item in tarifs],
}
return data
```

Comment: Посмотрите вариаты https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022066/how-to-serialize-sqlalchemy-result-to-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос снят. Реализовал с помощью flask_marshmallow. Отдельно прописал схему:

```
class TarifSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

После получения данных с базы конвертировал и отобразил клиенту:

```
tarifs = Tarif.query.all()
if tarifs is not None:
    tarif_schema = TarifSchema(many=True)
    data = tarif_schema.dump(tarifs)
    return jsonify(data)
```